# Blank textfields ignored in Rails 5 params for multipart forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

When using a multipart encoded form, blank textfields are being ignored and not passed through to the Rails params hash as empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to a bug in Rack 2.0.0.alpha. It has been fixed in commit [f2baf7b](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/f2baf7ba76f90d5977abc347fed3a6bb7d32e114) but as of the time of this post has not been included in a new release yet. I fixed this bug by using the master branch of the rack gem for now until a new release is made.